# How to Get number of post done by user

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Here is my question:
I have 4 tables which hold post done by user(say CatA,CatB,CatC and CatD, each table hold created_by column). My requirement is to get all the user available from table `USER` with post count (sum of post).

I am struggling to find answer from past 2 days and i'm still clueless.

Any idea is much appreciated.

---

```
SELECT    u.username,
          a.cnt + b.cnt + c.cnt + d.cnt AS total_posts
FROM      users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM CatA GROUP BY created_by) a
          ON u.id = a.created_by
LEFT JOIN (SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM CatB GROUP BY created_by) b
          ON u.id = b.created_by
LEFT JOIN (SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM CatC GROUP BY created_by) c
          ON u.id = c.created_by
LEFT JOIN (SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM CatD GROUP BY created_by) d
          ON u.id = d.created_by
ORDER BY total_posts DESC
```

This return me total post count on top (irrespective of user post count) like below instead of post count for each user

> username |  user1 |  user2 |  user3
>   total_posts | 11020 (Total post count) | NULL | NULL | and so on

More Info:

```
SELECT created_by, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM CatA GROUP BY created_by
```

This returns me:

> created_by   | 22 | 26 | 88 | 90
>   cnt          | 6 | 20 | 15 | 8

Comment: Use `JOIN` to join all the tabes where the userid is the one you want then count

Comment: Welcome to SO. Adding some code would be helpful, at the very least the table definitions, and maybe a query you have tried?

Comment: are you trying to say that each table (CatA, CatB, etc..) contains a create_by (better created_by) column? Better specify your tables, or make your example a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you have a separate table for each category (which is actually not the most optimal design by the way). What you can do to get the count of posts for all users is:

```
SELECT    u.*,
          a.cnt + b.cnt + c.cnt + d.cnt AS total_posts
FROM      users u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM CatA GROUP BY user_id) a
          ON u.user_id = a.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM CatB GROUP BY user_id) b
          ON u.user_id = b.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM CatC GROUP BY user_id) c
          ON u.user_id = c.user_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM CatD GROUP BY user_id) d
          ON u.user_id = d.user_id
```